How to use git submodule when trying to customise it?
basically I'm trying to customise huggingface's diffusers library to suit my case. In order to do that, I've cloned the diffusers library source code under my project folder.
So the directory structure is like
my_project
├── .venv
├── .git
├── my_root_src
│   ├── file_1.py
│   ├── file_2.py
├── diffusers  # this one has become submodule
│   ├── .git
│   ├── some_file_I_need_to_customise.py
.
.
.
└── .gitignore


I need to customise the diffusers source code.
The problem is,

As the git has suggested, I've submoduled diffusers library
But when I've made any changes and committed them, they do not appear on other hosts where I've cloned my_project repository

Basically, it seems like git submodule appears empty when cloned with a parent module.



What kind of actions could I take?

(Updated) By the way, the main reason I didn't fork the repo in the first place is because I tried to follow the below link.
https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/en/installation#editable-install

You committed your changes, did you push them?

I'm sure he doesn't actually want to modify the huggingface repo, or even have permission to do so.  Some folks do this by creating a set of patches, which they then apply automatically during a clone.  Some people just embed the files into their repos and cut the tie.

@TimRoberts "But when I've made any changes and committed them, they do not appear on other hosts where I've cloned my_project repository" They have to push their local changes somewhere if they expect them to appear in other clones of their repo. We need more information.

If you need to change the diffusers source code AND want those changes to appear when you clone my_project, you will need your own fork of diffusers to store your changes. Exactly how you do that depends on where you're storing your repositories.

@Schwern I committed them to my local submodule diffusers git repo, if that makes sense(And that is what git had suggested me, when I struggled with adding it to the stage)
So, I committed in my local diffusers repo and then committed what's been changed as a whole to my_project repo

@djmoon13 And you mentioned you're cloning my_project to other hots. Where is my_project stored?

Ah, let me give you some more detail. Basically, my_project is stored in my local and pushed to my remote github repo, but I'm using the code elsewhere, like in another machine to use its GPU for faster training

And the problem is, the modified diffusers code in my local repo, which is committed locally, and pushed to my github repo, does not appear when I've cloned my_project repo in another machine. The submodule appears to be empty

@djmoon13 Does the "Cloning a Project with Submodules" section of 7.11 Git Tools - Submodules answer your question?

@Schwern it seems like it doesn't match with my situation. git submodule init and git submodule update seem to fetch original diffusers commits, not my customised commits. Is my guess right...?

@djmoon13 Ok, you have both problems.

You have two problems.

the modified diffusers code in my local repo, which is committed locally, and pushed to my github repo, does not appear when I've cloned my_project repo in another machine. The submodule appears to be empty.

When you clone a repository which contains a submodule, you must also initialize and fetch that submodule.

git submodule init
git submodule update

Or you can clone with git clone --recurse-submodules.
See the Submodules section of the Pro Git book for more.


it seems like it doesn't match with my situation. git submodule init and git submodule update seem to fetch original diffusers commits, not my customised commits.

As with everything in Git, everything you do is local. That includes changes to your diffusers submodule. If you want those changes to be seen by others, they must be pushed to a server.
If you want to change the diffusers source code AND want those changes to appear when you clone my_project, you will need your own fork of diffusers to store your changes. A fork is where you maintain your own copy of the repository. You can make your own changes, and you can also update it from the original repository ("upstream").
diffusers is on Github so you can fork your own copy of the repository there. Then have your submodule in my_project point to your fork. Push your changes to your fork so they can be seen by your other clones.
You'll want to keep diffusers up to date with the original repository. Add it as a remote, fetch it, and merge the upstream's main branch into your local main branch.

git remote add upstream <url to original diffusers repo>.
git fetch upstream.
git merge upstream/main

Or you can use Github's syncing tool.
See Fork a repository and Synching a repository.

If this is the case, I assume that I have to remove the original submodule related diffusers and fork & clone the diffusers into the same directory. If so, is the submodule related concept still needed?

Since, the cloned forked repository will also be another git repository inside my_project repository, I guess git would suggest me to submodule it again

@djmoon13 You should be able to change the url your existing submodule is pointing at. I don't use submodules, a dependency manager is generally a better choice, but I believe git submodule set-url will do it.

Just carry your patched-diffusers history as a branch in your main repo, treat it as a worktree.
When you're setting it up for yourself, to work on your diffusers changes,
git remote add diffusers-upstream github:huggingface/diffusers
git fetch
git worktree add -b diffusers diffusers diffusers-upstream/main
git submodule add --reference ./ ./ diffusers

When people clone your project,
git clone your://project/url yourproject; cd $_
git worktree add diffusers :diffusers
git config submodule.diffusers.url ./

the worktree add and self-referential path url implements everything git submodule update --init would be doing, it sets up the submodule machinery to work properly, but without the bothersome need to go find the commits elsewhere. After the stutterstep above they can just git pull --recursive or git submodule update after pulling, all as usual.
You do need to be sure your submodule history sticks around in your main publishing repo, you want to tag the tips you push or make sure every published commit is an ancestor of a long-lived branch (for instance, if you're using your diffusers branch alone and not tagging, don't rebase it or the reference to previous commits used as submodule checkouts will be lost).
I wrote this about submodules long ago, they're really, really not hard. As with so much about Git, they're literally incredibly simple: so simple it's hard to believe.
For people who don't want to stray even a little off the beaten path, there's just forking the submodule repo and carrying your patches there.
